# SQL left join only works when I specify the columns of the right table (Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables, table1 (left table) with 33k rows and table2 with more than 33k rows. So when i do left join, the query should return 33k rows, right?

When i specify the columns from table2, the query returns 33k rows as expected. (query 1)

But when I select all columns from table2, the query only returns 26k rows. (query 2)

(At first i thought that this diff was bc of NULL values in table2, but I checked and the resulting query has NULL values too.)

Query 1 (returns 33k rows as expected):

```
SELECT A.id, A.col2, A.col3, B.ids, B.column1, B.column2,  
FROM table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS B 
ON A.id = B.ids
```

Query 2 (returns only 26k rows):

```
SELECT A.*, B.*  
FROM table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS B 
ON A.id = B.ids
```

(Redshift | PostgreSQL)

Comment: The columns select should not affect the number of rows returned.  It is possible to have expressions (in Postgres) that affect the number of rows, but not just columns.  A `WHERE` clause would, on the other hand.

Comment: Max number of returned rows are 33000 * 33000, if all rows have the same id's.

Comment: Buffer full? More columns gives more data per row...

Comment: You can filter larger dataset with `not in` smaller dataset, find the extra rows and debug why they are in one result and not in another with simple filters. Your current statement sounds not realistic.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the queries you provided? You are right that the result of left join should contain at least the number of rows in the left table (table1).  You may have more rows in the result (if there is one-to-many relation between the tables), but no less.